# Render session variable into exception.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony

I have problems with passing session variable into exception.html.twig.
The location of the exception.html.twig is:

\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Resources\views\Exception\exception.html.twig

In the controller I tried something like this:

```
$sess = $this->session->remove('param');
            $this->render('TwigBundle:Exception:exception.html.twig', array(
    'name' => $sess,
));
```

In the twig I tried to call it like:

```
{{ name }}
```

When I have $this->render in my code the page is loading, loading and doesn't want to load. How should I fix it?

Comment: You don't need to edit `vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Resources\views\Exception\exception.html.twig` file. This is bad practice. You need to override twig-template and put your code in your template. How to override template you can read here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates

Comment: 1. what is `$this->session`, how are you gettin it? 2. Are you returning the response?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How can I do such an operation? Or is their any way to remove session parameter straight from the Exception Controller?

Comment: xurshid29: 1. $this->session I get after initializing by  $this->session = new Session();  and then $this->session->set('param') in my Controller. 2. I return the response but there is no $sess variable, I just want to render it to the view by render method like I wrote

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the error page to customize it, as described in this Symfony cookbook entry:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: Hi, it seems that I have already overrode the exception page. From the link you provided, I figured out that I have to override the controller and perhaps the showAction. So I tried to add in this action:  $this->session = new Session();
        $this->session->remove('userQuery');   but it didn't help and page is still loading and doesn't even want to display the Exception page

Comment: I think I might be missing something here... Are you trying to throw a new exception or just change the look & feel of an existing one?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

action:

```
public function mySomeAction(Request $request) {
    ...
    $session = $request->getSession();
    ...

    $session->set('param', $value);
    ...
    $name = $session->remove('param');
    ..

    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Default:exception.html.twig', ['name' => $name]); // you create a template for exception page as mentioned above
}
```